# Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data "

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i am trying to send emails in laravel.But when trying to send it is genrating following error and mails are not sending. But everything worked fine in localhost without any problems.

```
  Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "lifeloveandotherthings94@gmail.com" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data
     ". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data"
```

Following is my code in .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=MyEmailPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@lifelove.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME='LifeLoveAndOtherThings'
```

I havent added additonal code in config/mail.php

```
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
    ],
],
```

I havent changed or added my emails in config/mail.php.I have set it up only in .env file. What is the issue here.

Comment: Have you enabled  "Allow less secure apps" on your google account security policy? Is 2- Factor authentication enabled for this gmail id?

Comment: Yup i have enabled and also generated App password

Comment: Does your password has any special characters? If yes enclose it with double quotes like -> MAIL_PASSWORD="MyEmailPassword"

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I have a similar error I enquoted about Charmy password and it worked like a charm.

```
MAIL_PASSWORD="YourEmailPassword"
```

If the problem still continues try using a username, password, and port number in double-quotes.

If you are using  your personal Gmail account then follow these steps :

1. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps
2. Take a look at the Security menu -> Apps with account access menu.
3. You must turn the option "Allow less secure apps" ON.

If you have already followed these steps, try restarting your project. and if it still doesn't work, please continue these steps :

1. Visit https://accounts.google.com/UnlockCaptcha
2. Click Continue button

Good luck!

Comment: This one was a lifesaver!

Answer (score 5):

The way you can do if you are using cpanel/whm :

1. in WHM search TweakSetting in Server Configuration
2. In Tweak Setting Page click on the Mail tab
3. Search smtp in Mail tab
4. search for Restrict outgoing SMTP to root, exim, and mailman (FKA SMTP Tweak)
   [image]
5. change the default on to off
6. Save the new setting

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 2):

For me, this was my problem

```
Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
```

This happened **suddenly after a few month in production** (before it worked perfectly). After having visited other post with similar question, none of which worked, the solution that I found was...

**to change the password and WAIT SOME TIME in order to be effective.**

*I know, I know*

I think that the password on outlook was expired after some time. The config was the same.

Comment: wait for how many minutes/days/months? I am having this problem with 2 servers. one is working perfect and other is giving this error with same credentials

Comment: I think it was like 10 minutes, or that magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

it was solved in my case by disabling the SMTP restriction option from WHM.
[image: WHM SMTP restriction]

Answer (score -1):

Try to solve it using either of these:
Your .env should be something like this..

**This if for domain email**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=mail.yourdomain.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=yourdomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="password"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

**This if for Gmail email**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=youremail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="yourPassword"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

**The second option**
Change

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

to

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Or vice versa

**The 3rd option**

Allow less secure apps in you email

I hope it solve your problem

Comment: it's tls not tsl

Answer (score -1):

Nothing posted above worked for me.

The bug was in password. It needed to be put in apostrophe.