# Send email from laravel in production

Tags: php, laravel, gmail, cpanel

I made a code to send an email using gmail in laravel, when I run it locally it works but in production(cpanel server) it doesn't.

> cPanel Versión    110.0 (build 17) Versión Apache 2.4.58

In Production:.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

> failed to authenticate on smtp server with username
> "*********@gmail.com" using 2 possible authenticators.
> authenticator login returned expected response code 235 but got code
> "535

Locally:
Normally send the message to different accounts.
env.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=test_email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=**************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

controller:

```
if (strlen($password_generado)>0) {
                # code...
                $usuario = DB::table('users')
                ->where('email', $request->correo)
                ->update([
                    'password' => $NewPass,
                ]);
                //Send email
                Mail::to($request->correo)->send(new Subscribe($request->correo,$request->nombre,$password_generado));
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 2;
            }
```

model:

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class Subscribe extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $email;
    public $user;
    public $pass;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($email, $user, $pass)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Gracias por unirte a GPC')
        ->markdown('emails.subscribers');
    }
}
```

view:

```
@component('mail::message')
# Bienvenido a GPC

Querido {{$user}}

Ten enviamos este mensaje para que puedas acceder al sistemas GPC
Usuario -> {{$email}}<br>
Contraseña -> {{$pass}}

@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'https://campus.com/login'])
Ingreso GPC
@endcomponent

Gracias,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

I don't understand why, I changed my email several times, but I don't know what the difference is, how can I fix that error please or if I can use another email server, I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: did you enable the 2-Step Verification on that gmail account?

Comment: @AliIsmaeel Yes, i did

Comment: You need to create app password so that password would be use for sending email which is now the secure way.

Comment: @KamranAllana I did that too, I'm using an app password to send email, but it only works locally.  The problem is when it run from cpanel serv

Comment: Use password in quotes `"*****"` and try. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61222340/authenticator-login-returned-expected-response-code-235-but-got-code-535-with

Comment: Try using `MAIL_MAILER=sendmail` inside `.env` file instead of `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`