LARAVEL: Gmail SMTP configured correctly and works in local XAMPP env but not working in cpanel hosted website
I get this error:

production.INFO: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username
"email@gmail.com" using the following authenticators: "LOGIN",
"PLAIN". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code "235"
but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication
data".". Authenticator "PLAIN" returned "Expected response code "235"
but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data".
production.ERROR: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username
"email@gmail.com" using the following authenticators: "LOGIN",
"PLAIN". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code "235"
but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication
data".". Authenticator "PLAIN" returned "Expected response code "235"
but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication
data".". {"exception":"[object]
(Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportException(code: 535):
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username
"email@gmail.com" using the following authenticators: "LOGIN",
"PLAIN". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code
"235" but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect
authentication data".". Authenticator "PLAIN" returned "Expected
response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535
Incorrect authentication data".". at
/to/path/vendor/symfony/mailer/Transport/Smtp/EsmtpTransport.php:212)

The problem is that I don't get any issue on xampp but this only happens on my uploaded website. (This has only recently started, maybe 15 days back and it was working before on uploaded site too)
The username is the email address used for logging into the gmail and the password was generated from "App Passwords" (2FA Account)
I've tried different encryptions, just to verify.
    MAIL_MAILER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
    MAIL_PORT=587
    MAIL_USERNAME=email@gmail.com
    MAIL_PASSWORD=smuacrrfmlrlqgsp
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
    MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=contact@domain.tld
    MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
    MAIL_TO_ADDRESS=sales@domain.tld

Anywhere I find similar issue threads, they keep mentioning the 2FA-UnsecureApps-AppPassword solution, which I know and I've already configured. I've talked to my hosting provider and they say they didn't put any SMTP restrictions from WHM.

You should remove your MAIL_PASSWORD from the question. It's not safe to have that kind of sensitive info out in the open. You should delete the app and create a new one for security. Keep your private stuff private!

Thanks but that's a dummy generated PW. Just to show absolutely precisely how there's no spacing mistake etc.

Thanks for clarifying, Manny! It's always good to be cautious.

Take a look at this thread maybe it is helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61222340/authenticator-login-returned-expected-response-code-235-but-got-code-535-with

I did see that post and the WHM issue seemed most plausible. But I have a shared hosting and my provider says he hasn't restricted SMTP.
If only there was some other way for me to check if he is true or not...

Have you tried creating a new Gmail app? Or maybe it's something to do with the wrong password.

Yes, already made 3 App Passwords just to re-check. They are not wrong since they work on local xampp.

1- First you need to check your DNS records on with hosting provider.
2- Try different config like:
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

3- Check the domain option in google app since the localhost is auto-allowed for testing maybe your domain is blocked.

Thanks for the comment.

What exactly should I check that could be missing? Like DKIM, SPF? (Last I checked they are there.... infact they don't matter since smtp driver is being use to access a google account)
Tested, not working
I think you meant ip and not domain. I'm technically getting this error while my laravel app tries to log in (not that my emails may go to spam).


Other possible options:
1-  Check if the host is blocking the ports (587, 465) for any reason.
2- Check for outgoing smtp restrictions (https://ibb.co/6NDZPgd)
3- Check for special characters in your password (# for example) .
